# Safari showing my div in wrong position

Tags: css, html

It's about this page http://chios-grill.de/anfahrt.html

In Safari and sometimes in Google Chrome the right text box just falls below the whole pages like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVWZY.jpg

It works nicely while offline but not while the page is online. Could it have to do something with the Google Maps embed?

If you need the code, tell me. Otherwise you can just use Google Chromes Developer Tool to look into it I guess.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is width problem, because I have updated the width for the div id='textbox' and it's gone down, try to give a little width just to make sure that is compatible for all the browsers.

This will fix this problem. Try it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the problem though. It had to do with the fact that the Maps embed had no float. Now everything is working fine!